# Problem Binding TableView prefWidthProperty to it's Parent Container's prefWidthProperty

Tags: java, javafx, binding, tableview

Relevant FXML :

```
<ScrollPane fx:id="scrollpane_var" hbarPolicy="NEVER" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" GridPane.columnSpan="3" GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.rowSpan="5">
         <content>
            <TableView fx:id="tableview_var" prefHeight="169.0" prefWidth="292.0">
              <columns>
                <TableColumn prefWidth="69.0" text="Quantité" />
                <TableColumn prefWidth="161.0" text="Nom" />
                  <TableColumn prefWidth="56.0" text="Prix" />
              </columns>
            </TableView>
         </content>
      </ScrollPane>
```

Controller class Code :

```
public class Lancer {

    @FXML // fx:id="scrollpane_var
    private ScrollPane scrollpane_var; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="tableview_var"
    private TableView<String> tableview_var; // Value injected by FXMLLoaderte void initialize()

    public void initialize() {
    tableview_var.prefWidthProperty().bind(scrollpane_var.prefWidthProperty());
    }
```

Visual Representation :

[Click to see Scenebuilder screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsZhH.png)

as the title says i'm trying to bind a TableView's width to it's Parent container and the documentation is a bit confusing as i am very new to GUI Applications .

This line of code is the furthest i've gottent and i dont know why it's not working :

```
 public void initialize() {
        tableview_var.prefWidthProperty().bind(scrollpane_var.prefWidthProperty());
        }
```

Comment: Note that `TableView` has built-in scrolling functionality and does not need to be wrapped in a `ScrollPane`.

Comment: java naming conventions please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `TableView` manages its own scrolling, so you should not be putting it inside a `ScrollPane` at all. Just omit the scroll pane from the layout entirely.

In general, if you want the content of a scroll pane to fit the available width of the scroll pane, you would use the [`fitToWidth` property](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html#fitToWidthProperty), instead of trying to use a binding. In general, binding the pref width like this is a bad idea; if the layout or container you are using doesn't provide the functionality you need, and it almost always will, you should subclass `Pane` and override `layoutChildren()` and other methods. Here, the `TableView` already provides scrolling, and in more general cases, the `ScrollPane` allows you to specify the content should fit the width of the scroll pane.

```xml
<ScrollPane ... fitToWidth="true>
    <!-- ... -->
</ScrollPane>
```

But again, here the scroll pane is redundant.

Comment: the answer is easier than i expected , i dont even need to do a binding, thank you sir